# showing invalid syntax in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, function, jupyter

> I am a newbie in programming. I am using Jupyter Notebook.
> I wa solving one problem in Hackerrank.
> I am getting invalid syntax while running this program 
>   my code is

```
meal_cost = float(input())
tip_percent = int(input())
tax_percent = int(input())


def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    return (meal_cost + ((meal_cost*tip_percent)/100 + ((meal_cost*tax_percent)/100)


p = solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
ans = str(round(p))
print (p)
```

> error is

```
     p = solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if I write it this way

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    totalCost = (meal_cost + ((meal_cost*tip_percent)/100) + ((meal_cost*tax_percent)/100)
    return (round(totalCost))

meal_cost = float(input())

tip_percent = int(input())

tax_percent = int(input())

p = solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)

print ( p )
```

it is showing

```
    meal_cost = float(input())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> I have solved this program using my own inputs and not using a function.
> But using function not able to understand where am I going wrong.
> Also I would like to know how I can write a return command in this function.

Comment: The problem is with parentheses on the lines where you have `(meal_cost + ((meal_cost*tip_percent)/100...`. You have more opening parentheses than closing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter still has some bugs and sometimes some things stay loaded in the cache so a safe bet is to restart the kernel to clear variables from memory.

But in your case you forgot a closing parentheses in this line:
`totalCost = (meal_cost + ((meal_costtip_percent)/100) + ((meal_costtax_percent)/100)`
- add a closing parentheses and it should work :)